# How to easily create a local SSH tunnel using pure Python

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko, portforwarding

I have a pretty simple task: using ssh, I want to create a tunnel that forwards traffic from my local machine to a specific port on a remote machine. I can do this from the command line:

```
ssh -N -L 123:127.0.0.1:456 user@remotehost
```

Then if I run:

```
telnet localhost 123
```

it's the equivalent of logging into `remotehost` and running

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 456
```

I've managed to do this with something along the lines of;

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-N', '-L', '%i:127.0.0.1:%i' % (new_port, old_port), ssh_user + '@' + ip_addr])
```

But now I want to move away from that and use only Python - no external processes.

I've tried using [fabric.context_managers.remote_tunnel](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.remote_tunnel) but unless I've misunderstood this is meant for creating a tunnel that starts at a remote location, not from the local machine. That is, it is the equivalent of SSHing into a remote machine and creating an SSH tunnel from there, which is silly for my purpose. I suppose I could set the remote host to actually be the local machine but this seems inefficient and honestly I don't even understand how to do that.

I've also tried [forward.py on paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py) and it doesn't work because my private key is encrypted. I'd like to modify the script to handle that, and also just simplify it for my needs, but both the script and the paramiko library are daunting and I don't know how to begin.

Surely there's an easy way to do this? I seem to be so close yet so far.

Comment: why don't you want to use a Popen or fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "pure Python"? Subprocess is bundled with standard python installation.

Subprocess and Fabric are designed for such tasks, why would you want to move away from them?

If you have, minimal tasks to be performed remotely e.g. check memory, hostname, etc. you can go ahead with suprocess. However if you have some big requirements, I would suggest going with fabric.

For your purpose where you have to work on the same machine, why not use subprocess with check_call or Popen. As an alternative, you can change your code altogether so as to be able to get into Unix core to achieve what the Linux commands do.